# django-q multple cron expression for a single job

Tags: django, cron, django-q, croniter

Is there a way to use multiple cron expression for a single job in Django-Q.
I want a schedule a job for different day of different month.

want to combine this-

```
At 11:00 on day-of-month 10, 20, and 30 in January and every month from March through December--

0 11 10,20 1,2,4-12 *



At 11:00 on day-of-month 10, 20, and 28 in February.--

0 11 10,20,28 2 *
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can do that, a better approach will be to keep a single cron that runs on a daily basis and check is there any cron that needs to be run today(we may store the cron info in a database table).

Comment: Can you suggest me how to use django-q properly.It seems to execute a job right after starting qcluster instead of proper scheduling time.